# how can I delete entire text in input field with single click of backspace

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how can I delete entire text in input filed with single click of backspace USING ANGULAR JS. I have an input field with has a number "12345678" I want to delete the entire number in the input field when I hit backspace.

Comment: Make sure you indicate whether you're using AngularJS or Angular 2+, they are two different things that require a different syntax. Right now, you're saying AngularJS in your text, but have added both "angularjs" and "angular" tags to your question.

Comment: If you read the post you can see that I have included Angular JS in bold.

Comment: Sure, but my point remains. The "angular" tag explicitly says " For the older AngularJS (1.x) web framework, use the angularjs tag."

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using ngModel for your input, you could do something like this:

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)" [(ngModel)]="myString" />
```

And in your .ts file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  myString = 'hello';

  onKeyUp(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 8) {
      this.myString = '';
    }
  }
}
```

Working Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhbshe